# Issue while adding no of days to current date in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am adding days to date in jQuery as below:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
alert(today.getDate()+23);
```

But it is adding days only, for example in above alert I am getting 43 for today's date (28 August).

Comment: Just a tiny bit of correction: you are not using jQuery (which is JavaScript library), but standard JavaScript objects: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
var today = new Date();
var newdate = new Date();
newdate.setDate(today.getDate()+29);
alert(newdate);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hrRzQ/

Answer (score 2):

```
var today = new Date();

today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
today.setDate(today.getDate()+23)
console.log(today)
```

Comment: This is clean way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setDate first and then `alert(today.getDate())`

try as below :

```
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate() + 23); 
alert(today.getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(document).ready(function () {     

 var today = new Date();
 today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
 today.setDate(today.getDate() + 30);
 alert(today);

});
```